# How to use loops in Unity Job System

Tags: unity, c#

I want to calculate the distance between the list of game objects So element will check its distance with every other element and so on, I am doing this with following code it works but not efficient enough. Can anyone tell me the correct way to use loops in the job system?

```
enter struct Field: IJobParallelForTransform
{
    public NativeArray<float> Dist;
    public Vector3 PlayerPos;

    public void Execute(int i, TransformAccess transform)
    {

          Dist[i] = Vector3.Distance(PlayerPos, transform.position);


    }
}

public List<Transform> Childrens;//All gameobjects list

public TransformAccessArray ALlObjects;



NativeArray<float> distances;



void Start ()

{



    ALlObjects = new TransformAccessArray(0, -1);



    distances = new NativeArray<float>(Childrens.Count, Allocator.Persistent);



}



   void Update()

{

    for (int i = 0; i < Childrens.Count; i++)

    {

        Field job1 = new Field()

        {

            Dist = distances,

            PlayerPos= Childrens[i].position,



        };

        JobHandle jH = job1.Schedule(ALlObjects);

        jH.Complete();

        for (int j = 0; j < distances.Length; j++)

        {



            if (distances[j] <= 0.8f && distances[j] > 0)

            {



                break;

            }

            if (distances[j] > 0.8f )

            {



            }



        }



    }

}
```

Comment: When you say it's "not efficient enough," what's the specific symptom of inefficiency we need to address? And what's the feature these distances are serving? There might be structural ways we can improve efficiency by, say, only checking the subset of distances that are potentially relevant.

Comment: @DMGregory When I try to compare distance without job system performance was better which means maybe I am not using it correctly.

Comment: Tell us more. We don't charge by the word here, so be very descriptive about what feature you're implementing and what results you've observed.